# Using a standalone Python script on local machine to connect to and store data in GCP Datastore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to have a standalone Python script on my local machine connect to and store data in GCP Datastore?

I have a text file with tonnes of structured data. I just want to store it in a NoSQL GCP datastore. I don't want to have to create a web app or anything, just a python script to open the file, read each line and store it in a cloud datastore.

All the tutorials I see online start with some Flask/Jinja app on App Engine or something and I feel this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial) shows how to build a simple command-line TaskList application that stores data in the Google Cloud Datastore API. You could adapt it to read data from a text file.